# Unknown log related to Cassandra

Tags: cassandra, cql

Got the following info log:

`Query SELECT column1, column2 FROM table_name WHERE productId IN ('column1_value') is not prepared on /<example-ip-address>:9042, preparing before retrying executing. Seeing this message a few times is fine, but seeing it a lot may be source of performance problems`

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

This happens when you send bound query with prepared query ID that is unknown for given node. Node may not "know" this query because of several reasons:

- Node crashed and lost cache of prepared statements
- Prepared statement was evicted from cache (you should see corresponding message server side). This may happen if somebody prepares too many queries
- There were options set to not prepare queries on all nodes (see [documentation](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/3.7/manual/statements/prepared/#preparing-on-multiple-nodes))

You need to check these hypothesis before continue. I think that it could happen because of 2nd item - this may happen if people prepare "literal" queries that don't have bind markers.